# JavaFX: load resource from other package - NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, javafx, fxml

I know there have already been some questions about relative paths, but I Keep failing to get JavaFX FXML loader to load a resource from a package other than itself.

The loading class is located in the package gui.controllers and the fxml file `BarSheet.fxml` is located in the package `gui.resources`.
What should i now put in :

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("src/gui/resources/BarSheet.fxml"));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: The fault was in the fact that my fxml file contained an error so i didnt know when i entered the right path because it would still not work...
The path should start with / to indicate the path starting from the root followed by packages/filename. So in my case

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui/resources/BarSheet.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement when you have a package like com.company.view, and inside you have the `.fxml` file in order to make this work you have to put the line like this:

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/company/view/file.fxml"));
```